# C language i get an error in my code

Tags: c, error-code

hello I am searching where I did the wrong step?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    int account_on_the_bank=25;
    printf("how much money do you have in the banque? \n");
    scanf("%f",account_on_the_bank);
    printf("Vous avez %d euros sur votre compte",account_on_the_bank);
    return 0;
}
```

**where's my problem???? it shows windows has stop working**
I have tried everything the same problem shows up always?

Comment: i have corrected %d and %f nothing happens ;; the same error

Comment: You might want to read [a `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Check the format table, and the argument types for each format.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problematic line:

```
    scanf("%f",account_on_the_bank);
```

It has wrong specifier and also not passing the address of the variable to scanf.

It should be:

```
    scanf("%d", &account_on_the_bank);
```

Comment: yes i notice that my brother thank you and i have fixed it but still the same problem after run the problem a message from windows 10 windows stop working .....

Comment: That's the only in your code. Perhaps, you didn't recompile it ? or there's an issue with your IDE?

Comment: still this Process returned 255 (0xFF)

Comment: @hiicham07 That's not an error. That's what your `main` returned. But that should've been "_Process returned 0 (0x00)_" as you return 0. No idea why it is 255.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the basics of C

---

You have error in your `scanf()`

```
scanf("%f",account_on_the_bank);
        ^  ^
```

It should be

```
scanf("%d",&account_on_the_bank);
        ^  ^
```

because int needs `%d` as specifier, and `scanf()` needs address of the variable in which you want to store the read value(address is obtained by using `&`)

Comment: @hiicham07, Hope you saved the program and compiled it again!

Comment: Process returned 255 (0xFF)    still this